# Rをバッチファイルのみで実行する方法

Tags: r, batch-file

Rをインストール済みのWindowsPCでバッチファイルからRを実行したいと考えております。
2行の短いプログラムなので、プログラムファイルは別に置かずに、バッチファイル内にコードを記述する方法を探していますが見つかりません。
（バッチファイルからRプログラムを実行する方法は見つかるのですが。）
対応できる方法はありますでしょうか。ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: バッチファイルではなくて、`R`のスクリプトファイル(拡張子`.r`)そのものを実行可能にする設定を行ってみてはどうでしょう？ こちらのPythonでの例を応用してみれば良いのでは？ [Windows のファイル拡張子の関連付け](https://qiita.com/TsuneoNakanishi/items/5f0248c82bf073cf2868), [WindowsでanacondaのPythonに引数が渡せない？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40319/26370)

Answer (score 1):

.R のスクリプトをコマンドラインから実行するには `Rscript` コマンドを使用します。

```
Rscript ~/myscript.R
```

のように書くだけで大丈夫です。

Rscript コマンド自体がインストールされているか確認するには
`which Rscript` とタイプしてみてください